# Read command works locally and fail with wget

Tags: shell-script, wget, read

I am trying to use `read` command with `wget`, for that I am using a simple .sh script:

```
# echo "Please answer by : -> yes <- or -> no <-"
# read answer
# echo $answer
```

This code works fine locally, but the `read` command failed remotely with `wget`, it finishes without waiting an answer:

```
# wget -qO - 'https://testserver/pub/test.sh' | bash -x
# + echo 'Please answer by : -> yes <- or -> no <-'
# Please answer by : -> yes <- or -> no <-
# + read answer
#
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You might want to read from the terminal, not from stdin: `read answer < /dev/tty`

Comment: You may also run your script as `bash -c "$(wget -qO - 'https://testserver/pub/test.sh')"`. It won't be great, though, since the allowed length of your script will be capped by the command line's max length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your script with `bash` in the terminal, bash gets your *standard input* (you only have one) from the keyboard.

```
keyboard -> script
```

When you feed the script to `bash` over a pipe, that pipe becomes the *standard input*. So your problem is not related to wget, if you did this:

```
cat test.sh | bash -x
```

you'd have the same behaviour, because now the input comes from the pipe, not the keyboard. And `bash` scripts will inherit that *standard input*.

```
pipe -> script
```

As soon as the data in the pipe finishes, so does bash and the script.

A way to solve that is to download, and then run (you don't need the `-O` but I'm trying to keep your line mostly as-is). Something like this:

```
$ wget -qO test.sh 'https://testserver/pub/test.sh' && bash test.sh
```

Comment: Tnxs man for the explanation, you solved my problem.